# Is there possibility in Prometheus alerts calculate another alert status?

Tags: alerting, prometheus

I want to make an ALERT with IF that contains expression that depends on another alert status. Is that ever possible somehow? I know about alert inhibition with alermanager but I need not to firing some alerts at all in some cases.
Prometheus v.1.7.2

Comment: The version you're using would be helpful..

Comment: v.1.7.2. Updated main post